# Git - reset a branch that has been merged to another into previous commit

Tags: git, version-control

In my git project, I follow the following flow:

I am working on a branch named **mybranch**, push commits and when I want to make 'a version', I **merge mybranch** into '**develop**' branch, then switch back to **mybranch** and repeat the same process.

Accidentally after a merge from **mybranch to develop**, I **forgot to switch branches** and stayed to 'develop' branch and pushed some commits straight to it (let's call them **develop-commit-1, develop-commit-2, develop-commit-3**).

Then '**mybranch**' where I was working was **behind 'develop'** and I needed these commits (they were destined for this branch originally) so I thought that **merging the develop branch back to the 'mybranch'** will do the trick' (**bad decision**).

To my surprise, now I see the git history of 'develop' branch containing the commits of 'mybranch' and from the GUI I see the branches have been aligned (because of the vice versa merge git thinks they are the same or something?).

I want to return to my previous workflow (keep clean the develop branch and add only merges from mybranch into it), so I am thinking about resetting the 'develop' branch to the commit where last merged 'mybranch' into it, and then just merge 'mybranch' back to it as I used to do, will that work? I am really scared whether the reset of 'develop' branch back to that commit will affect 'mybranch' since they have been merged between them (and **mybranch** contains these 3 commits that are after the commit point where I want the develop branch to be reset, any advice here?

I can definitely give more information on that in case the description is not clear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branches are *pointers* to a single commit (a branch does *not* mean a collection of commits). Resetting a branch cannot have an effect on other branches.

So you want to simply reset develop and keep your branch `mybranch`. Eventually, force-push your rewritten develop:

```
git branch -f develop "$commit_before_your_accident"
git push origin +develop:develop
```

The 3 commits that were previously reachable through the `develop` pointer are no longer reachable through it, only through the `mybranch` pointer.

But since your branch still contains the merge from develop and no new commits were made on develop, the next merge to develop is going to be a fast-forward. To force a real merge, you have to merge with the `--no-ff` flag.

Comment: Thanks for your response, won't I have a problem from the fact that 'develop' branch has 3 commits after the reset point I want to go at, and this branch has been merged into 'mybranch'?

Comment: @NickAth After you execute `git branch -f ...`, develop no longer has 3 additional commits.  That command caused develop to refer to a new commit.  (The commit that it used to refer to.)  Stop thinking about branches as a collection of commits, and think about the branch name as just being a reference to a single commit.

Comment: I did reset and pushed into develop branch and now it is in the state "commit_before_your_accident", but now I want to merge 'mybranch' into develop branch as I did in the past and when I merge through sourcetree I do not see changed files on stage but a status that my 'your branch is ahead of origin/develop by 10 commits'

Comment: @NickAth If you hadn't performed any new commits on develop, your branch is in fact commits ahead. If you still want to perform a real merge, run `git merge --no-ff`

Comment: I still get the message that my local branch is ahead of remote by 'x' commits even by using 'git merge --no-ff' though..

Comment: @NickAth "of _remote_"? Have you pushed your branch. If your local branch has commits that are not pushed to the remote, it will be "ahead". This is independent of any merges that you might or might not have performed.

Comment: I hate to admit that pulling from the remote branch of develop before merging the 'mybranch' into it fixed the issue, now I see the changes as changed files... -_- something weird I see now is that all these changes go straight to the staged files (as they would be done by 'git add . ', it doesnt cause me any problem but any idea why this happens? Thanks a lot for your support again :)

Comment: @NickAth staged files almost certainly mean a conflict (either from creating the merge commit or by applying an autostash)